# How can I run code slightly later than the onCreate() and onStart() events?

Tags: android

I have a list view that is populated through a string-array in the xml, not run time and I'm trying to set the background color of specific items in the list using:

```
listView.getChildAt(x).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I need this to happen before it's visible, but it gives an error when I use it in onCreate() or onStart(), but works if I run it on a button press. I've tried searching for an answer but can't seem to find any event that happens late enough for it to work.

Comment: may be you are doing this before setting adapter. Try to set after populating listview.

Comment: is X some static / fixed value?

Comment: Could you paste more of the code? where are you pulling the data of the xml?

Comment: you can probably do this in the adapter class. Based off the position you are at, change the background color. The ONLY problem you may have is listview items are reused.

Comment: Inside my list view xml I have, android:entries="@array/exam_array" which populates the list view from a string-array in strings.xml. I've done this since it's easier to change the font and add a second line with a different font in each item.

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` would be the best place to do this, but you don't have access with the way you are doing this with `android:entries=...`. Instead, you can post a runnable to the message queue to change the color after layout occurs like the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.layout).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            findViewById(R.id.view).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
        }
    });
}
```

Here I have used a simple `View` for demonstration but the same technique should work for your `ListView`.

Here is the XML I used if you want to work with it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) to `post`. The runnable kicks off before `onStart()`. So, if that's a requirement, then this way may not work for you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, I'll have to re create the items through an array/adapter instead of xml.